# Creating a CCK record in a MySQL database

Tags: drupal-6

I want to create a CCK node through MySQL. I have these three main tables that I know are involved:

1. It appears that the **Node** table is used as a foriegn key for all the records in the node_revision and CCK tables. It also holds the title, create date, etc.
2. There are CCK tables that hold the **CCK** Field values
3. There is the the **node_revision** table that holds the body of the content.

Pseudocode for this might be:

```
Insert Into NodeTable //Title and other node fields
Select nId of New Node //To use as foreign key for insert into CCK & Revision table
Insert Into Node_Revision //body field, using NodeId as foreign key
Insert Into CCK_table //fields in form other than Title & Body
```

Are there any other tables that need to be touched to replicate doing it through the UI?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little tricky because it depends on what other modules you have installed (ex. location) and how they hook in -- is there a reason you wouldn't want to do this "programmatically" by bootstrapping Drupal? Here's a great guide for how you could do that emulating the form module and using drupal_execute:

http://thedrupalblog.com/programmatically-create-any-node-type-using-drupal-execute

Comment: I'm creating my own web services that are going to be invoked by the android app. I want to create a push/pull sync, and this is the "push" part. I create a "node" in my android application(really a SqlLite table with roughly the same properties as my drupal node). Directly after that, I send a SOAP request which is processed and creates the node in drupal.